# is there any function like getimagesize() php in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have create upload file , but I have stack when I want to validation that content is image or not, because if validate extension only we can manipulate with fake content and valid extension.

is there function similar getimagesize() php in javascript?

Comment: He can still manipulate validation on the client, console->debugger; , whatever you try to do. you'll still need validation on the server.

Comment: 1. Upload Image Through AJAX and Also Perform Validation.
2. Get the results back to JS.
3. If it is not a image then create one more AJAX call and delete that file using php
4. Notify User That File is not valid

Comment: @AspiringAqib " and Also Perform Validation" just to complete: ya, server side

Comment: @roasted do you have a other way then you are welcome! I have this only solution which i mentioned above.

Comment: @camus of course validation on server is fix, but if in the client side I can give validation i think will be good security...:)

Comment: @AspiringAqib no, i don't have, i find your solution quite good

Comment: hey someone got something down there ;)

Comment: @Aspiring Aqib that is nice idea, but I'm worried because I'm using File Render HTML5 to access image url and showing before i'm send to server and I was manipulated that image and showing progress uploading using ajax...

Comment: now, whats on your mind? what you wanna do?

Comment: now is fix this issue , I'm use like you suggestion check to the server and giving error message...:)

Answer (score 2):

In some of the more modern browsers you can load an image into a canvas context (this doesn't actually have to be displayed on the page) and get the dimensions from that.

I did something like this in a CMS I built to allow the image to be scanned for certain colours without it having to be uploaded to a server first:

```
$('section.content form input[name=image]').change(function(){
    file = this.files[0];

    if(file.type.match(/image.*/))
    {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        // add this into an onload, as it takes time (albeit very little) to load the image into the DOM object
        img.onload = function(){
            canv = document.getElementById('product_image');
            if(!canv || !canv.getContext)
                return; // problem getting the canvas element

            // get the canvas context that we'll be using and the width of the canvas & image
            var ctx = canv.getContext('2d');
            var width = img.width;
            var height = img.height;
        };
        // put the file into the img object, triggering the img onload handler above
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {img.src = e.target.result};
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's need new element for context and i'm wondering with  cross browser, but you answer is good one, I'm waiting another answer is more simple...:)

Comment: I don't think there is any other way without involving a call/upload to the server. This isn't supported by all browsers, I've only tested in Chrome and Firefox so far, but IE (even 9) is probably not going to work.